# Send accessibility events not linked to any composable in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, talkback

Trying to announce accessibility when showing a pop up/Dialog. After hours of searching found the following code but this does not work for jetpack compose.

Looking for something similar to the code given below but in **Jetpack Compose**

```
if (manager.isEnabled) {
    val e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain()
    e.eventType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT
    e.className = ChangePassword::class.java.name
    e.packageName = context.packageName
    e.text.add(errorMessage)
    manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all those looking for an answer, there's one simple property in **Jetpack Compose** that will work. Which is `liveRegion`

You can find the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/LiveRegionMode

and it can be used as follow;

```
Text(modifier = Text(
                text = "Page Title,
                color = White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .focusable()
                    .clearAndSetSemantics {
                        this.contentDescription = accSkipPermission
                        liveRegion = LiveRegionMode.Assertive
                    }
            ))
```