How to announce a notification by Talkback in Compose?
I have a "toast" (custom composable using Box, which slides in and out after some time) notification, and I want talkback to read up the contentDescription  "immediately" regardless what the user is doing or what is in the focus currently. I tried to set a focusRequest modifier and liveregion sematics, but this just doesn't wants to work. Also tried localview.announceForAccessibility("....") which works but it looks kinda ugly to me. Are there a better of doing this  ?
#1

fun Toast(
    modifier
    state
) {

    val focusRequester = remember {FocusRequester()}
    Box(...........)
        )
        {
        Row{
            ......
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = state.icon),
                contentDescription = state.message,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(.5F).sematics {
                    liveregion = LiveRegionMode.Assetive
                }.focusRequester(focusRequester).focusable(),
            )
            Text(text = state.messageString, modifier.clearAndSetSematics{})
        }
    }
    
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}

#2
val localView = LocalView.current
fun toast {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        localView.announceForAccessibility(..........)
    }
}

(ofc this not the whole code of the toast, just only wanted the "important" part)


Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360883/1166926 ?

@HardikTrivedi just did, still no. I have to navigate to the toast (e.g with tab)
